# seaborn displot column label

Tags: python, label, seaborn

Muy buenas me gustaría añadir el valor de cada columna sobre la columna en el siguiente displot de seaborn:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
g = sns.displot(df, x="Main Category", kde=True, height=12, color="teal", linewidth=1, aspect=2, hue="Main Category")

g.set(xlabel = "LOB", title="Line of Business", ylabel="Number of SKU´s")
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que las respuestas sean más acertadas. Como no pusiste tus datos completos tuve que responder con un ejemplo genérico. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Para poder hacerlo debes acceder a los `patches` de cada barra, iterando por cada eje.

Cada barra tiene un valor `xy`, la altura y el ancho. La altura será la que vamos a utilizar para mostrar el valor de la barra

**Nota:** Como no pusiste tus datos completos tuve que utilizar un ejemplo genérico así que tendrás que adaptarlo a tu código.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.displot(df, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True, height=12, color="teal", linewidth=1, aspect=2)
g.set(xlabel = "LOB", title="Line of Business", ylabel="Number of SKU´s")
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=2), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente gráfico:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: muchas gracias!!