# Histograma de un dataframe con Python

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito hacer este ejercicio en particular:

**Elabora un histograma en el que se observe la distribución de datos de la población por país que vive con menos de $1.90 dólares al día. El histograma debe contener los siguientes elementos:**

- Título
- Etiquetas en los ejes
- Límites del eje "y" desde el 0 hasta el 100
- 20 bines
- Color de los bordes del histograma: Negro
- Grosor de los bordes: 1

**Las 10 primeras filas de mi dataframe:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi código:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.title('Histograma de La población por país que vive con menos de $1.90 dólares al día ')
    plt.hist(df['Country'],bins=20,alpha=0.5,label='Country',edgecolor = "black")                      
    plt.hist(df['< $1.90[1]'],bins=20,alpha=0.5,label='Poblacion con < $1.90',edgecolor = "black")     
    plt.legend()
```

Y el error que me da es que en la salida, específicamente en el eje x me debería de mostrar los nombres de los paises pero **me sale borroso y no se entiende nada es completamente ininteligible**, será que me podrían ayudar porfavor. Adjunto el histograma de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es necesario que los países que no cumplan con dicha condición, digamos `> 1,90$` aparezcan en la grafica?

Comment: No, no es necesario, solo necesito hacer el histograma entre la columna Country y la columna < $1.90[1].

Comment: Estaba pensando que podrías usar indexación condicional para separar los países debajo de ese índice, lo cual seria algo como `df[(df['<$1.90'] < 1.90)]`?.

Comment: Buen día, aquí hay otra pregunta similar que tal vez te pueda servir: [seaborn displot column label](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/528850/seaborn-displot-column-label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar usar `vlines` para conseguir un resultado parecido al que quieres, pero tal vez tengas que agregar unos cuantos detalles a la grafica, yo he hecho lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'Unnamed': [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 13, 15], 'Country': ['Albania', 'Algeria', 'Angola', 'Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bangladesh', 'Belarus'], '<$1.90': [1.7, 0.5, 47.6, 1.0, 2.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0, 14.8, 0.0], '<$3.20': [10.4, 3.9, 69.8, 3.0, 13.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.0, 52.9, 0.0], '<$5.50': [38.0, 29.2, 87.2, 9.6, 50.4, 0.7, 0.7, 8.2, 84.5, 0.4], 'index': range(0, 10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = df[['Country', '<$1.90', '<$3.20', '<$5.50']].groupby('Country').apply(lambda x: x.mean(numeric_only=True))
```

Esto devuelve un *dataframe* asi:

```
            <$1.90  <$3.20  <$5.50
Country
Albania        1.7    10.4    38.0
Algeria        0.5     3.9    29.2
Angola        47.6    69.8    87.2
Argentina      1.0     3.0     9.6
Armenia        2.1    13.0    50.4
Australia      0.5     0.7     0.7
Austria        0.3     0.4     0.7
Azerbaijan     0.0     0.0     8.2
Bangladesh    14.8    52.9    84.5
Belarus        0.0     0.0     0.4
```

Es obvio que hay mas países a evaluar pero me estoy basando en el ejemplo.

Si usas `plt.hist(df)` se grafica sin usar los nombres de los países en el *eje x* pero las barras son de diferentes proporciones, a diferencia de `vlines` he logrado obtener un resultado parecido al que describes, pero creo que aun le falta agregarle algunos detalles importantes.

```
plt.vlines(x=dfx.index, ymin=0, ymax=dfx['<$1.90'], color='firebrick', alpha=0.7, linewidth=20)
plt.xticks(df.index, df.Country, rotation=60, horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=8)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.title("Paises con media < $1.90")
plt.show()
```

[image: vlines ejemplo]

sin establecer `ylim(0, 100)`
[image: vlines ejemplo]

Comment: Ufff sos un genio amigoo, me ayudo muchísimo, mil gracias, que Dios lo bendiga!!

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando Seaborn llegue a este código, suponiendo que quiero hacer el histograma solo de los primeros 10 datos del dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sns
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
grafico = sns.countplot ( x= 'Country', hue = '< $1.90[1]', data = df1)
grafico.set(title = 'Histograma de La población por país que vive con menos de $1.90 dólares al día',
           xlabel ='Country', ylabel ='Poblacion con < $1.90')
plt.xticks(rotation=75)
plt.show()
```

El error es que en la salida me presenta los histogramas todos del mismo nivel, es decir la misma altura a 1.0, como puedo solucionar eso? Porque debe ser acorde a la Población con < $1.90.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que debes usar el dataframe df['< $1.90[1]'] en el parámetro data para que solo coja los valores de la clase '< $1.90[1]'

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado a rotar las etiquetas del eje x? Se están escribiendo de forma horizontal y se montan unas sobre otras. Tal vez rotándolas 90 grados podría solucionarte un poco el tema.

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Si lo prefieres, también puedes rotarlo 45 grados en vez de 90 del siguiente modo:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
```

Por otro lado, si estás agrupando una gran cantidad de países en cada BIN, ten cuidado de no usar todos los nombres juntos (algunos de esos bines pueden agrupar a muchos y generar una cadena muy larga como etiqueta). Para ese caso te recomiendo que uses etiquetas del tipo rango, por ejemplo: [0-5], [6-10], etc. (NOTA: si cada barra representa aun único pais, ignora este último párrafo).

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Me ayudaste para la rotación, gracias amigo, ahí tengo otra duda, los histogramas me salen todos a la misma altura y eso no debería ser así.